# JavaScriptCore crash on iOS9

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios9, javascriptcore

Encountering a crash for a iOS9 only.  The crash is manifesting in JavaScriptCore though I'm not certain it has anything to do with JavaScriptCore.  I'm more inclined to believe this is an issue with memory exhaustion more specifically and possible virtual memory exhaustion.  As noted in the screenshot free RAM is exceptionally low so it's definitely not an ideal situation.  I don't know enough about iOS internals to entirely what's going on here but wondering if there's others out there who have encountered this type of thing with iOS9.  This was not an issue for me on iOS 7.x, iOS 8.x

[image: iOS9 crash]

Comment: Any luck with this? I have seen pratically the same crash for an app using iOS9 only, with similar to the above, showing messages from WTF: HashTable... but the crash is from Javascriptcore.

Comment: Hey @StuartM yes did make some progress with this.  I will make an answer post about it.  In our case the issue was a JSContext object we were creating for running JS scripts and then releasing it when it shouldn't have been release.  The Xcode static analyzer actually picked this up.  Once I changed the code to not release when it wasn't supposed to all seemed to work well.

Comment: thanks @Rob Segal. Unfortunately we do not use any custom JS so it doesn't look to be related I imagine it is a third party library crash we will need to continue to monitor. Thanks

Comment: Sure no problem @StuartM.  I'm fairly convinced something changed with JavaScriptCore with iOS9/Xcode7 so my feel is yeah could definitely be something with a 3rd-party lib.  Especially if vendors haven't updated to build against iOS9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case appears to have been from releasing a JSContext object from a section of code which was not the owner that was setup to run JavaScript.  Xcode flagged it in the static analyzer and once the release call was removed all was well.  I'm a bit hesitant to say this was for sure the issue since the crash didn't happen 100% of the time but given the testing before/after the change it seems pretty likely.