# Report: YouTube iFrame player crashes in iOS 9.0.x UIWebView (from 2016-09-02)

Tags: ios, youtube, uiwebview, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

> The crash is reproducible in an iOS 9.0.x device via opening this [official demo page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) from app with UIWebView (like Facebook Messenger)

I'm using YouTube iFrame player based on this [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) in my iOS UIWebView, however, from 9/2, it starts crashing the app (iOS 9.0.x ONLY) with stack such as below:

```js
Crashed: JavaScriptCore::Marking

0  JavaScriptCore                 0x1859f65b0 JSC::JSEnvironmentRecord::visitChildren(JSC::JSCell*, JSC::SlotVisitor&) + 224
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x1859f65ec JSC::JSEnvironmentRecord::visitChildren(JSC::JSCell*, JSC::SlotVisitor&) + 284
2  JavaScriptCore                 0x1855c34bc JSC::SlotVisitor::drain() + 300
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x1855c446c JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 288
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x1858e4bd0 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 120
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x1855bb4e4 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x1855bb3f4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x199e87b3c _pthread_body + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x199e87aa0 _pthread_body + 154
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x199e85030 thread_start + 4
```

Since that it's reproducible in iOS 9.0.x device with official demo page, I assume that there may be something wrong about YouTube iFrame player changes on 9/2.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315696/webthread-javascriptcore-crash-what-this-crash-report-means) which states that these crashes are the result of [bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139654).

Also based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17652694/5832311), if your application is crashing randomly, then you need to analyze your code. You can do that on XCode. Try to open your Project in XCode. In Product menu, you will find the Analyze option (cmd+shift+B). Make sure you have selected "iOS Device" before analyzing it.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33926995/5832311) might also help.

> The issue in this case appears to have been from releasing a JSContext object from a section of code which was not the owner that was setup to run JavaScript. Xcode flagged it in the static analyzer and once the release call was removed all was well. I'm a bit hesitant to say this was for sure the issue since the crash didn't happen 100% of the time but given the testing before/after the change it seems pretty likely.

Comment: Thanks Abielita, looks like YouTube fixed that issue yesterday, crashes down to ZERO =)